# php bootstrap error with modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have the below scripts running but once I add a remote file link for the modal, it will not update.

1. I want to edit from a modal
2. within that modal window, confirm the data was submitted successfully
3. on close, refresh the crud.

Any help will be appreciated.

I'm modifying the class.crud.php file to include this line

removing

```
<a href="edit-data.php?edit_id=<?php print($row['id']); ?>"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>
```

replacing with

```
<a data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-info" href="edit-data.php?edit_id=<?php print($row['id']); ?>" data-target="#myModal"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>
```

INDEX.PHP

```
<?php include_once 'dbconfig.php'; ?>
<?php include_once 'header.php'; ?>

<div class="clearfix"></div>

<div class="container">
     <table class='table table-bordered table-responsive'>
     <tr>
     <th>#</th>
     <th>First Name</th>
     <th>Last Name</th>
     <th>E - mail ID</th>
     <th>Contact No</th>
     <th colspan="2" align="center">Actions</th>
     </tr>
     <?php
  $query = "SELECT * FROM tblUsers";       
  $records_per_page=10;
  $newquery = $crud->paging($query,$records_per_page);
  $crud->dataview($newquery);
  ?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="7" align="center">
    <div class="pagination-wrap">
            <?php $crud->paginglink($query,$records_per_page); ?>
         </div>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>


</div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
        </div> <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div> <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div> <!-- /.modal -->

<?php include_once 'footer.php'; ?>
```

CLASS.CRUD.PHP

```
    public function update($id,$fname,$lname,$email,$level_id)
 {
  try
  {
   $stmt=$this->db->prepare("UPDATE tblUsers SET firstname=:fname, 
                                                 lastname=:lname, 
                email=:email, 
                level_id=:contact
             WHERE id=:id ");
   $stmt->bindparam(":fname",$fname);
   $stmt->bindparam(":lname",$lname);
   $stmt->bindparam(":email",$email);
   $stmt->bindparam(":contact",$level_id);
   $stmt->bindparam(":id",$id);
   $stmt->execute();

   return true; 
  }
  catch(PDOException $e)
  {
   echo $e->getMessage(); 
   return false;
  }
 }

 public function delete($id)
 {
  $stmt = $this->db->prepare("DELETE FROM tblUsers WHERE id=:id");
  $stmt->bindparam(":id",$id);
  $stmt->execute();
  return true;
 }

 /* paging */

 public function dataview($query)
 {
  $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
  $stmt->execute();

  if($stmt->rowCount()>0)
  {
   while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
   {
    ?>
                <tr>
                <td><?php print($row['id']); ?></td>
                <td><?php print($row['firstname']); ?></td>
                <td><?php print($row['lastname']); ?></td>
                <td><?php print($row['email']); ?></td>
                <td><?php print($row['level_id']); ?></td>
                <td align="center">
                <a href="edit-data.php?edit_id=<?php print($row['id']); ?>"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                <a href="delete.php?delete_id=<?php print($row['id']); ?>"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></i></a>
                </td>
                </tr>
                <?php
   }
  }
  else
  {
   ?>
            <tr>
            <td>Nothing here...</td>
            </tr>
            <?php
  }

 }
```

EDIT-DATA.PHP

```
<?php
   include_once 'dbconfig.php';
   if(isset($_POST['btn-update']))
   {
    $id = $_GET['edit_id'];
    $fname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $level_id = $_POST['level_id'];

    if($crud->update($id,$fname,$lname,$email,$level_id))
    {
     $msg = "<div class='alert alert-info'>
       <strong>WOW!</strong> Record was updated successfully <a href='index.php'>HOME</a>!
       </div>";
    }
    else
    {
     $msg = "<div class='alert alert-warning'>
       <strong>SORRY!</strong> ERROR while updating record !
       </div>";
    }
   }

   if(isset($_GET['edit_id']))
   {
    $id = $_GET['edit_id'];
    extract($crud->getID($id)); 
   }

   ?>
   <?php include_once 'header.php'; ?>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="container">
   <?php
      if(isset($msg))
      {
       echo $msg;
      }
      ?>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<br />
<div class="modal-header" id="myModal">
   <form method='post'>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="email">First Name:</label>
         <input type='text' name='firstname' class='form-control' value="<?php echo $firstname; ?>" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="email">Last Name:</label>
         <input type='text' name='lastname' class='form-control' value="<?php echo $lastname; ?>" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="email">Email:</label>
         <input type='text' name='email' class='form-control' value="<?php echo $email; ?>" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="email">Level ID:</label>
         <input type='text' name='level_id' class='form-control' value="<?php echo $level_id; ?>" required>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btn-update">Save changes</button>
      </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Use Ajax to load `edit-data.php?edit_id=<?php print($row['id']); ?>` in the bootstrap modal

Comment: I'm unsure of what you mean, can you please expand on that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this method. 
Load a bootstrap modal through ajax

Wrap your `a` tag inside `div` for easy visibility.

```
   <div id="edit_btn">
     <a data-toggle="modal" id="modal-<?php print($row['id']);?> " class="btn btn-info" href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>
      </div>
```

**index.php**

```
    <?php include_once 'dbconfig.php'; ?>
<?php include_once 'header.php'; ?>

<div class="clearfix"></div>

<div class="container">
     <table class='table table-bordered table-responsive'>
     <tr>
     <th>#</th>
     <th>First Name</th>
     <th>Last Name</th>
     <th>E - mail ID</th>
     <th>Contact No</th>
     <th colspan="2" align="center">Actions</th>
     </tr>
     <?php
  $query = "SELECT * FROM tblUsers";
  $records_per_page=10;
  $newquery = $crud->paging($query,$records_per_page);
  $crud->dataview($newquery);
  ?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="7" align="center">
    <div class="pagination-wrap">
            <?php $crud->paginglink($query,$records_per_page); ?>
         </div>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>

</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#edit_btn a").click(function() {
    var Id = jQuery(this).attr("id");
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            'modal_id' : Id,
        },
        url : "edit-data.php?edit_id=<?php print($row['id']); ?>",
        success: function(response) {
            if(response) {
                $('body').append(response);
                $('#modal_'+Id).modal('show');
                $(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', modal_id, function (event) {
                    $(this).remove();
                });
            } else {
                alert('Error');
            }
        }
    });
});
});
</script>
```

Shift modal and insert it inside `EDIT-DATA.PHP`

```
    <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
<?php
   include_once 'dbconfig.php';
   if(isset($_POST['btn-update']))
   {
    $id = $_GET['edit_id'];
    $fname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $level_id = $_POST['level_id'];

    if($crud->update($id,$fname,$lname,$email,$level_id))
    {
     $msg = "<div class='alert alert-info'>
       <strong>WOW!</strong> Record was updated successfully <a href='index.php'>HOME</a>!
       </div>";
    }
    else
    {
     $msg = "<div class='alert alert-warning'>
       <strong>SORRY!</strong> ERROR while updating record !
       </div>";
    }
   }

   if(isset($_GET['edit_id']))
   {
    $id = $_GET['edit_id'];
    extract($crud->getID($id));
   }

   ?>
   <?php include_once 'header.php'; ?>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="container">
   <?php
      if(isset($msg))
      {
       echo $msg;
      }
      ?>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<br />
<div class="modal-header" id="myModal">
   <form method='post'>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="email">First Name:</label>
         <input type='text' name='firstname' class='form-control' value="<?php echo $firstname; ?>" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="email">Last Name:</label>
         <input type='text' name='lastname' class='form-control' value="<?php echo $lastname; ?>" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="email">Email:</label>
         <input type='text' name='email' class='form-control' value="<?php echo $email; ?>" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="email">Level ID:</label>
         <input type='text' name='level_id' class='form-control' value="<?php echo $level_id; ?>" required>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btn-update">Save changes</button>
      </div>
   </form>
</div>
</div> <!-- /.modal-content -->
</div> <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div> <!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: many thanks nulldev, unfortunately it opened in edit-data.php separately and, Is there anything else i could provide ? I post the html of both index and edit-data

Comment: To be honest I didn't understand very clearly what your trying to denote.

Comment: And I can't test this example you provided because I don't have extra files your using. But if your patient enough I can write for you a clear example based on my view and you use it as a reference to solve your problem.

Comment: thanks for your help - the css file missing is <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

Comment: Then include it, `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

Answer (score 0):

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <title>Bootstrap</title>
      <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
      <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
               <h1>nav bar</h1>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
      <div class="container">
      <table class='table table-bordered table-responsive'>
         <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>E - mail ID</th>
            <th>Contact No</th>
            <th colspan="2" align="center">Actions</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>James</td>
            <td>Smith</td>
            <td>james@gmail.com</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td align="center">
               <div id="edit_btn">
                  <a data-toggle="modal" id="modal-1 " class="btn btn-info" href="edit-data.php?edit_id=1">test</i></a>
               </div>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
               <a href="delete.php?delete_id=1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></i></a>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>admin@gmail.com</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td align="center">
               <div id="edit_btn">
                  <a data-toggle="modal" id="modal-2 " class="btn btn-info" href="edit-data.php?edit_id=2">test</i></a>
               </div>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
               <a href="delete.php?delete_id=2"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></i></a>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>james.Smith@gmail.com</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td align="center">
               <div id="edit_btn">
                  <a data-toggle="modal" id="modal-3 " class="btn btn-info" href="edit-data.php?edit_id=3">test</i></a>
               </div>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
               <a href="delete.php?delete_id=3"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></i></a>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="7" align="center">
               <div class="pagination-wrap">
                  <ul class="pagination">
                     <li><a href='/test/index.php?page_no=1' style='color:red;'>1</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
         <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-content -->
         </div>
         <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.modal -->
      <script type='text/javascript'>
         $(document).ready(function() {
         $("#edit_btn a").on('click',function() {
             var Id = jQuery(this).attr("id");
             $.ajax({
                 type: 'POST',
                 data: {
                     'modal_id' : Id,
                 },
                 url : "edit-data.php?edit_id=",
                 success: function(response) {
                     if(response) {
                         $('body').append(response);
                         $('#modal_'+Id).modal('show');
                         $(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', modal_id, function (event) {
                             $(this).remove();
                         });
                     } else {
                         alert('Error');
                     }
                 }
             });
         });
         });
      </script>
      <div class="container">
         <div class="alert alert-info">

         </div>
      </div>
      <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

edit-date.php

```
<!-- Modal -->
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>PDO OOP CRUD using Bootstrap</title>
<link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"> 
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="navbar-header">
<h1>nav bar</h1>
        </div>
         </div>

</div>




<div class="modal-header" id="myModal">
<div class="modal-body">
   <form method='post'>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="email">First Name:</label>
         <input type='text' name='firstname' class='form-control' value="Phil" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="email">Last Name:</label>
         <input type='text' name='lastname' class='form-control' value="Smith" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="email">Email:</label>
         <input type='text' name='email' class='form-control' value="phil@gmail.com" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="email">Level ID:</label>
         <input type='text' name='level_id' class='form-control' value="6" required>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btn-update">Save changes</button>
      </div>
   </form>
   </div>
</div>
```